# Visualizing HOG feature, why the direction of gradient is perpendicular to the real gradient orientation

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

The direction of the gradient is usually point from a darker area to a lighter area, or conversely. However for visualizing the HOG, why the "star dials" are along the direction of intensity/color changes.

I do understand how we get the orientation and magnitude of the gradients.

But, I do not understand the idea behind the visualization of HOG. Here is an example, the third "star dial" on the first row. Should not the directions of the gradient point to directions perpendicular to the red lines?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HOG visualizing is to better '**see**' what in feature spaces. So the directions of **outline(not gradient)** at some points are displayed.

Is your image from [SATYA's blog](http://www.learnopencv.com/histogram-of-oriented-gradients/)? That's good mateiral. You can also read [this](http://web.mit.edu/vondrick/ihog/). It's a project introducing the tools to visualize HOG feature spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the visualization tool that is being used. For example when using `skimage.feature.hog()` with `visualize=True`, it produces a hog image described as follows:

> For each cell and orientation bin, the image contains a line segment
>   that is centered at the cell center, is **perpendicular** to the midpoint
>   of the range of angles spanned by the orientation bin, and has
>   intensity proportional to the corresponding histogram value.

See the [documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.feature.html#skimage.feature.hog) for more details. So what you are seeing in these visualizations are lines (nine for each cell) at angles perpendicular to the orientation-bin angles, not the gradient orientations themselves.